# Why the catch block of AggregateException was not sufficient to handle cancellations?

Tags: c#, task, task-parallel-library, cancellation-token, c#-12.0

Run the following code:

```
using static System.Console;
WriteLine("Handling cancellations and exceptions.");
CancellationTokenSource cts = new();
CancellationToken token = cts.Token;

var transferMoney = Task<string>.Factory.StartNew(
 () =>
 {
     WriteLine($"Initiating the money transfer.");
     int progressBar = 0;
     WriteLine("Press c to cancel withing 5 sec.");
     // Assuming the task will take 5 seconds.
     // So, after every second, we'll increase the progress by 20%
     for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
     {
         token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
         Thread.Sleep(1000);
         progressBar += 20;
         WriteLine($"Progress:{progressBar}%");
     }
     return "Money transfer is completed.";
 }, token);

var input = ReadKey().KeyChar;
if (input.Equals('c'))
{
    WriteLine("\nCancellation is requested.");
    cts.Cancel();
}
try
{

    transferMoney.Wait();   
    WriteLine(transferMoney.Result);
}
catch (AggregateException ae)
{
    ae.Handle(e =>
    {
        WriteLine($"Caught error :  {e.Message}");
        return true;
    });
}

catch (OperationCanceledException oce)
{
    WriteLine($"Caught error due to cancellation :{oce.Message}");
}

WriteLine($"Payment processing status: {transferMoney.Status}");
WriteLine("Thank you, visit again!");
```

Here is a sample output( expected behavior- no doubt):

```
Handling cancellations and exceptions.
Initiating the money transfer.
Press c to cancel withing 5 sec.
Progress:20%
Progress:40%
Progress:60%
c
Cancellation is requested.
Progress:80%
Caught error :  A task was canceled.
Payment processing status: Canceled
Thank you, visit again!
```

Now update the try block with any of the following statement:

```
try
{
    //transferMoney.Wait();
    transferMoney.Wait(token); 
    //await transferMoney; //Same observation
    // There is no change in the remaining code
```

And run the code again. Here is a sample output.

```
Handling cancellations and exceptions.
Initiating the money transfer.
Press c to cancel withing 5 sec.
Progress:20%
Progress:40%
c
Cancellation is requested.
**Caught error due to cancellation :The operation was canceled.**
Payment processing status: Running
Thank you, visit again!
```

Notice that this time the catch block for AggregateException was not sufficient to handle OperationCanceledException. I'd like to know the reason behind this. Can you please share your thoughts-where am I missing?
[Additional note: I understand that in earlier case, wait() can throw only AggregateException but this overloaded version of Wait(i.e. Wait(token)) can throw OperationCancelledException as well. ]

Comment: _"I understand that in earlier case, wait() can throw only AggregateException but this overloaded version of Wait(i.e. Wait(token)) can throw OperationCancelledException as well."_ - so what do you need to be explained? `OperationCancelledException` will be thrown if the passed to the `Wait` token is cancelled, that's it, that is how the method is designed.

Comment: @Guru Stron: "so what do you need to be explained?"- I was expecting "the exception for cancellation operation" will also be wrapped inside AggregateExeption. It is because as per the theory, all exceptions that can be raised by various tasks should be consolidated under it. "OperationCancelledException will be thrown if the passed to the Wait token is cancelled, that's it, that is how the method is designed. "- Do you mean that this is a special case?

Comment: As a side note, `Task.Run` is preferable to `​Task<string>.Factory.StartNew`. See [this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/task-run-vs-task-factory-startnew/ "Task.Run vs Task.Factory.StartNew") for an explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [`Task.Wait(CancellationToken)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.wait?view=net-8.0#system-threading-tasks-task-wait(system-threading-cancellationtoken)) docs:

> but the wait is canceled once the cancellation token is cancelled and an `OperationCanceledException` is thrown.

And

> The `Wait(CancellationToken)` method creates a cancelable wait; that is, it causes the current thread to wait until one of the following occurs:
>
> - The task completes.
> - The cancellation token is canceled. In this case, the call to the `Wait(CancellationToken)` method throws an `OperationCanceledException`.

Your wait is cancelled in the second case so you get `OperationCanceledException`, i.e. the method can understand that the cancellation (of monitored token) has happened, not some random error (which will go to the "task completes" case and will result in `AggregateException`) .

`OperationCanceledException` does not inherit from the `AggregateException` so the `catch(AggregateException)` can't handle it.

`OperationCanceledException` is prioritized over the any other exception if any happened during the task execution. From the [`Task.Wait` source code](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs,2776):

```cs
// If cancellation was requested and the task was canceled, throw an
// OperationCanceledException.  This is prioritized ahead of the ThrowIfExceptional
// call to bring more determinism to cases where the same token is used to
// cancel the Wait and to cancel the Task.  
// Otherwise, there's a race condition between
// whether the Wait or the Task observes the cancellation request first,
// and different exceptions result from the different cases.

if (IsCanceled) cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

// If an exception occurred, or the task was cancelled, throw an exception.

ThrowIfExceptional(true);
```

Comment: Ok. Let me rephrase the question a little bit: ThrowIfCancellationRequested basically throws OperationCanceledException and it was caught inside the catch(AggregationException) when I use wait. But it was not sufficient when I use wait(token), but in this case also OperationCanceledException was raised. And here is the confusion.

Comment: @VaskaranSarcar it uses the same token you are waiting on. Try using different ones.

Comment: @VaskaranSarcar _"and it was caught inside the catch(AggregationException) when I use wait"_ - no, it was not, `AggregateException` was caught which contained/wrapped `OperationCanceledException` (an could have contained any other).

Comment: @VaskaranSarcar added excerpt from the source code.

Comment: First, thanks for the help and knowledge sharing. There is no confusion about some of the points that you said e.g "it uses the same token you are waiting on. Try using different ones"  and "OperationCanceledException does not inherit from the AggregateException so the catch(AggregateException) can't handle it."- True
Actually, I am wondering about: in case of wait(), it is wrapping the exception but Why the same principle did not apply for wait(token).Do you mean that it is purely a design decision? The included excerpt is for a different overload of wait i.e. Wait(int, CancellationToken)

Comment: 1) _"The included excerpt is for a different overload of wait"_ - yes and no, `Task.Wait(CancellationToken)` calls it, you can check it yourself 2) _"it is wrapping the exception but Why the same principle did not apply for wait(token)"_ the first one is not cancellable, so it treats the cancellation of the token as a "usual" error so it wraps it into the aggregate exception, the second one is cancellable and is cancelled, those a 2 semantically/logically quite different cases hence the exception. There are cases when cancellation can be handled (i.e. without propagating exception).

Comment: "the first one is not cancellable, so it treats the cancellation of the token as a "usual" error so it wraps it into the aggregate exception, the second one is cancellable and is cancelled, those a 2 semantically/logically quite different cases hence the exception."--seems very much logical. Accepting the answer.